# Помогите с реализацией модели (MVC) в QT

Tags: c++, qt, mvc, qt5

У меня есть две структуры:

```
struct Some2 {
    int id;
    QString description;
};

struct Some {
    QString name;
    int id;
    QList<Some2> child;
};
```

И в основной программе будет получен `QList<Some>`. Интерфейс программы показан ниже:
[image: Окно приложения]

И у меня есть вопросы:

1. Сколько в итоге классов моделей нужно создать: один общий или 2 класса (для `Some` и для `Some2` каждый свой)?
2. Какой класс выбрать как родительский для отображения всех полей: `QAbstractListModel` или `QAbstractItemModel`?
3. Как при изменении выбранной строчки в `Some` изменять список в `Some2`?

---

**UDP**: Есть связанный вопрос [Что не так с моей моделью MVC?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/989951/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8E-mvc).

Comment: Первые два пункта целиком зависят от ваших потребностей. Что касается 3-его, то это нужно сделать через метод вашей модели

Comment: Если делать через один класс у меня возникают сложности отображения. Поэтому сейчас пробую реализовать с помощью двух классов. Тк 2 класса я пробую реализовать через класс `QAbstractListModel`, но я еще не знаю, получится ли. До третьего мне еще долго