# Что не так с моей моделью MVC?

Tags: c++, qt, mvc, qt5

Сделал модель, и пример данных, но они не отображаются ни в `tableView`, ни в `columnView`. Что делаю не так?

Вопрос связан с [Помогите с реализацией модели (MVC) в QT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/989880/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-mvc-%D0%B2-qt).

Структура проекта:
[image: Структура проекта]

Окно приложения
[image: Окно приложения]
Скриншот окна
[image: Скриншот окна]

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "somemodel.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QList<Some> b;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        Some s;
        s.id = i + 1;
        s.name = QString("Name%1").arg(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
            Some2 s2;
            s2.id = (i + 1) * 10 + j;
            s2.description = QString("Description: %1").arg((i + 1) * 10 + j);
            s.child.append(s2);
        }
        b.append(s);
    }
    SomeModel *sm = new SomeModel(b, this);
    ui->tableView->setModel(sm);
    ui->columnView->setModel(sm);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() { delete ui; }
```

**somemodel.h**

```
#ifndef SOMEMODEL_H
#define SOMEMODEL_H

#include <QAbstractListModel>

struct Some2 {
    static const QStringList FIELD_TEXT;
    int id;
    QString description;
};

struct Some {
    static const QStringList FIELD_TEXT;
    QString name;
    int id;
    QList<Some2> child;
    QString operator[] (const int index) const;
};

class SomeModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SomeModel(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QAbstractListModel(parent) { }
    SomeModel(QList<Some> bases, QObject *parent = nullptr)
        : QAbstractListModel(parent), _bases(bases) {  }

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const override;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override;
protected:
    QList<Some> _bases;
public:
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const override;
};

#endif // SOMEMODEL_H
```

**somemodel.cpp**

```
#include "somemodel.h"

// Some / Some2
const QStringList Some2::FIELD_TEXT = QStringList() << "ID" << "Description";
const QStringList Some::FIELD_TEXT = QStringList() << "Name" << "ID";

QString Some::operator[](const int index) const
{
    if (index == 0) { return name; }
    if (index == 1) { return QString::number(id); }
    return nullptr;
}

// SomeModel
int SomeModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (!parent.isValid()) { return 0; }
    return _bases.size();
}

int SomeModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (!parent.isValid()) { return 0; }
    return Some::FIELD_TEXT.size();
}

QVariant SomeModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid()) { return QVariant(); }
    if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= _bases.size()
            || index.column() < 0 || index.column() >= 2) { return QVariant(); }
    if (role != Qt::DisplayRole) { return QVariant(); }

    return _bases.at(index.row())[index.column()];
}

QVariant SomeModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
{
    if (role != Qt::DisplayRole) { return QVariant(); }
    if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal) {
        return Some::FIELD_TEXT.at(section);   // можно добавить проверку на sect < FIELD.size()
    } else if (orientation == Qt::Vertical) {
        return QString::number(section);
    }
    return QVariant();
}
```

---

**UDP**:
При дебаге обнаружил, что `rowCount, columnCount` вызывается с некорректным parent (`parent.isValid() == false`). Как это исправить?

Comment: Вы приложение запускаете и у вас там нет данных?

А то в скриншоте у вас дизайнер форм открыт, в котором ничего из того что вы в конструкторе MainWindow написали отображаться не будет

Comment: Добавил скрин. В приложении нет данных - да. Почему нет данных?

Comment: Не знаю, советую добавить дебажный вывод в методы rowCount, columnCount, data (или в отладчике посмотреть). Ну то есть выясните, с какими параметрами вызываются эти методы и правильные ли данные вы отдаёте. Я бы с этого начал

Comment: добавил UDP. Параметр parent невалидный. Как исправить?

Comment: Он вроде и не должен быть валидным. Ну в смысле `if (parent.isValid()) return 0; return _bases.size();` Если вам пришёл валидный родитель, это значит что у вас просят количество строк/столбцов у данного элемента, если не валидный, значит количество строк/столбцов у корня. Эти индексы описывают некоторое дерево (для моделей, описывающих деревья, например дерево папок). Для таблицы у вас один корневой элемент (единственный, с невалидным индексом), с каким-то количество столбцов/строк.

Comment: Для дерева папок у вас есть корень (диска, невалидный индекс), в нём какое-то количество файлов/папок (строки) с полями (столбцы - иконка, имя, атрибуты, время редактирования), и для каждой папки/файла её индекс (уже валидный) можно отдавать в rowCount/ColumnCount, а в ответ возвращать для папок количество вложенных элементов, для файлов - ничего (0 строк 0 столбцов). Папки ведь можно раскрыть и посмотреть что внутри, а файлы - листья в дереве. По-моему так

Comment: исправил, и заработало. Так что для rowCount/columnCount на валидность проверять не надо?

Comment: QAbstractItemModel - для сложных иерархических моделей (там может появиться необходимость обрабатывать валидные элементы, вместо того чтобы возвращать ноль). Для списков есть QAbstractListModel, для таблиц - QAbstractTableModel. В этих двух интерфейсах как правило вы будете для невалидных индексов возвращать количество строк/столбцов в вашем списке/таблицы, а валидные игнорировать (возвращать нули). Так что на валидность проверять надо всегда, только поведение меняется в зависимости от модели, которую вы используете.

Comment: А вообще - [Model View Progamming in qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#model-subclassing-reference). Там и про модели разные с картинками, и куча примеров.